# How to Unselect with Image Picker in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, select, unselect

I'm unable to unselect an option in Rails using Image Picker gem.  The select function works fine.  Using jQuery to call .imagepicker on "select".   I need to be able to unselect an option.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Here's the jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("select:not(#countertop_countertype_id)").val('').imagepicker({
  show_label:   true,
  clicked:function(){

    console.log($(this).find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").data('img-src'));

      }
    });

 });
```